# Linq to NHibernate and Group By

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I'm using the current Linq provider for NHibernate (version 2.1).

I have two entities: VideoGame and GameDeveloper, with a many-to-one
relationship between them.
I'm trying to perform a query of this sort, which counts the number of
video games each game developer has:

```
from v in session.Linq<VideoGame>()
group by v.Developer into developerGroup
select new {developerGroup.Key.Name, Count = developerGroup.Count()}
```

Enumerating this query causes an exception - "could not resolve
property Key of Entities.VideoGame".
Now, if I group by v.Developer.Id it works, but I can't select the
Name column and show it in the results. I could group by
v.Developer.Name, but it doesn't seem right, as two developers might
have the same name.

I know the current Linq provider is not being developed any more, but
would appreciate any advice on the situation.

Comment: Nope. Guess I'll have to wait to NHibernate 3.0 and the new Linq provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>How about</strike>

```
from v in session.Linq<VideoGame>()
group by v.Developer into developerGroup
select new {key = developerGroup.Key, count = developerGroup.Count()}
```

Seems like `group by` is broken in the 2.1 NHibernate LINQ provider. A while ago Steve Strong [blogged](http://blogs.imeta.co.uk/sstrong/archive/2009/12/16/823.aspx) that `group by` is in the [trunk](http://www.hornget.net/packages/orm/nhibernate/nhibernate-trunk) so if you are feeling adventurous enough and not willing to wait on 3.0 then that could be an option.

Or you could use a brute force solution something like this

```
from v in (from vg in session.Linq<VideoGame>() select vg).ToList()
group by v.Developer into developerGroup
select new {developerGroup.Key.Name, Count = developerGroup.Count()};
```

Comment: Be aware that the brute force above gets all videogames from the database.