# Can I write this query using the criteria API or am I stuck with HQL?

Tags: nhibernate

I have the following query which I would like to write using the criteria api of NH.

```
select status, count(1) from (select distinct Status, post_id from post_statistics) tbl group by status
```

each post_id can exist multiple times in post_statistics

e.g.

id post_id status
1  1       open
1  1       edit
1  1       open
1  2       open

so the query should return the following results:

status  count
open    2
edit    1

thx in advance.

Comment: I think you need something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1983477/735864

Answer (score 0):

mappings, classes?
if i'm thinking right, with a proper mapping this would effectively be something like

(pseudo-HQL)

```
select stat.Name, count(stat.Posts) from status stat
```

Comment: thanks Jaguar, I was asking about ICriteria. I know i can do it in HQL.